# Next.js application is not getting hosted to localhost:3000

Tags: next.js, localhost, unknown-host, readlink

My Next.Js Application is not getting hosted to localhost:3000 and keeps throwing this error at console.

[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\Users\MAYANK JHA\OneDrive\Desktop\AI_Form Builder\ai-form-builder.next\server\app\page.js'] {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'readlink',
path: 'C:\Users\MAYANK JHA\OneDrive\Desktop\AI_Form Builder\ai-form-builder.next\server\app\page.js'
}

Please Help

I tried to run the next.js app through npm run dev which is giving me this error continuously

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the npm error {errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'readlink'}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71443635/what-causes-the-npm-error-errno-4094-code-unknown-syscall-readlink)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a few things here.

1. Clean NPM cache - `npm cache clean --force`
2. Delete the `package-lock.json`
3. Delete `node_modules` and reinstall them.
4. Or as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71443635/what-causes-the-npm-error-errno-4094-code-unknown-syscall-readlink) said, delete the `.next` folder and try again.

If none of those work, you should try to reinstall Node and NPM completely.